# How to tell mysql to skip a column if it is empty or null with out processing

Tags: mysql, case

I have a table called stocks having some 5 columns contain data.Out of 5 some columns may empty.Below is my table structure.

```
+------------+------------+------------+--------+--------+
| level1     | level2     | level3     | level4 | level5 |
+------------+------------+------------+--------+--------+
| 2015-04-01 | 01.04.2015 | 01.04.2015 |        |        |
+------------+------------+------------+--------+--------+
```

Some date columns having date in string format. Now i want to add some days to level1, level2 and level3 columns and need to compare those columns with some other date in my where clause.
Below is my query to add some days to level1,level2 and level3 columns.

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(level1,INTERVAL 28 DAY) level1, DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(level2,'%d.%m.%Y'),INTERVAL 28 DAY) level2, 
DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(level3,'%d.%m.%Y'),INTERVAL 28 DAY) level3,level4,level5 
FROM stocks WHERE  stock= '4046228057941' AND
DATE_ADD(level1,INTERVAL 28 DAY)>='2015-04-01' AND
DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(level2,'%d.%m.%Y'),INTERVAL 28 DAY) >='2015-04-01' AND
DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(level3,'%d.%m.%Y'),INTERVAL 28 DAY) >='2015-04-01'


+------------+------------+------------+--------+--------+
| level1     | level2     | level3     | level4 | level5 |
+------------+------------+------------+--------+--------+
| 2015-04-29 | 2015-04-29 | 2015-04-29 |        |        |
+------------+------------+------------+--------+--------+
```

But i need to compare level4 and level5 columns also. Now level 4 and level5 are empty. But when i add level4 and level5 comparisons to the above query i am getting empty result.

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(level1,INTERVAL 28 DAY) level1, DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(level2,'%d.%m.%Y'),INTERVAL 28 DAY) level2, 
DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(level3,'%d.%m.%Y'),INTERVAL 28 DAY) level3,level4,level5 
FROM stocks WHERE  EAN = '4046228057941' AND
DATE_ADD(level1,INTERVAL 28 DAY)>='2015-04-01' AND
DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(level2,'%d.%m.%Y'),INTERVAL 28 DAY) >='2015-04-01' AND
DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(level3,'%d.%m.%Y'),INTERVAL 28 DAY) >='2015-04-01' AND
DATE(`level4`)='2015-04-01' AND DATE(`level5`)='2015-04-01'
```

But now my desired out put will be even if any column is empty my query need to skip that empty column and need to check the column which is having value. 
How can i achieve this ?Any help will be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use an OR condition.

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(level1, INTERVAL 28 DAY) level1,
       DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(level2, '%d.%m.%Y'), INTERVAL 28 DAY) level2,
       DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(level3, '%d.%m.%Y'), INTERVAL 28 DAY) level3,
       level4,
       level5 
  FROM stocks 
 WHERE EAN = '4046228057941' 
   AND (level1 IS NULL OR DATE_ADD(level1, INTERVAL 28 DAY) >= '2015-04-01')
   AND (level2 IS NULL OR DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(level2, '%d.%m.%Y'), INTERVAL 28 DAY) >= '2015-04-01')
   AND (level3 IS NULL OR DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(level3, '%d.%m.%Y'), INTERVAL 28 DAY) >= '2015-04-01' )
   AND (level4 IS NULL OR DATE(`level4`) = '2015-04-01')
   AND (level5 IS NULL OR DATE(`level5`) = '2015-04-01')
```

Note that if your "empty columns" are not nulls you should use another condition. For example:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(level1, INTERVAL 28 DAY) level1,
       DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(level2, '%d.%m.%Y'), INTERVAL 28 DAY) level2,
       DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(level3, '%d.%m.%Y'), INTERVAL 28 DAY) level3,
       level4,
       level5 
  FROM stocks 
 WHERE EAN = '4046228057941' 
   AND (LENGTH(level1) = 0 OR DATE_ADD(level1, INTERVAL 28 DAY) >= '2015-04-01')
   AND (LENGTH(level2) = 0 OR DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(level2, '%d.%m.%Y'), INTERVAL 28 DAY) >= '2015-04-01')
   AND (LENGTH(level3) = 0 OR DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(level3, '%d.%m.%Y'), INTERVAL 28 DAY) >= '2015-04-01' )
   AND (LENGTH(level4) = 0 OR DATE(`level4`) = '2015-04-01')
   AND (LENGTH(level5) = 0 OR DATE(`level5`) = '2015-04-01')
```

Comment: I tried with the above query, but still i am getting empty result.

Comment: What are the values of level4 and level5 columns? Are them empty strings instead of nulls?

Comment: I just edited the original answer with an alternative query. Can you try it?

Comment: yes, still i am getting empty record. If i omit these two lines AND (LENGTH(level4) > 0 OR DATE(`level4`) = '2015-04-01')
   AND (LENGTH(level5) > 0 OR DATE(`level5`) = '2015-04-01') i am getting record, otherwise getting empty rows :(

Comment: In that case I'm afraid I can't help without looking at your data. Can you post your a sample of your table in SQL Fiddle?

Comment: Sure , in 2 mins i will add

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72601/discussion-between-jordi-llull-and-user3408779).